# as if they didn't already have plenty to be demoralised about -- plenty?

Tags: meaning

Example with [a context](http://news.yahoo.com/future-bleak-russias-cowed-opposition-155140138.html):

> The psychological blow of his murder was "very demoralising for the opposition, as if they didn't already **have plenty** to be demoralised about," said Gaddy.

According to the dictionary, the word *plenty*, when used as a pronoun, simply means a large amount. But what I've noticed is that there are always a bunch of additional words that come along with it, such as *of something* (example: *we have plenty of that back home* or *there's plenty of food in the house*). And I think that's the most common way I've heard it used. In the example sentence above, however, the word is used completely on its own. Is this kind of usage also possible?

Comment: as BobRhodes mentioned, this use of "plenty" is better understood as an adjective, describing an implied "of things", i.e. "as if they didn't already have plenty *of things* to be demoralised about."

Comment: The dictionary calls it a pronoun.

Comment: It is a simple lookup the definition in a [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/plenty) question. You might have to look at the example sentences there, if that is not too much trouble.

Comment: Condescending sarcasm isn't particularly helpful to the cause, doulos.  Furthermore, it's easy to get confused by the dictionary definition, since it only has examples that say "plenty of something" rather than just "plenty".  So I don't agree with your position either.

Comment: Well perhaps @BobRodes it wouldn't trouble you yourself to actually click on the link and actually click on the phrase MORE EXAMPLE SENTENCES and see what you have said is false. Next, I can address the OP however I may like; this one has an annoying habit of clogging the board with definition questions.

Comment: Condescension and sarcasm don't serve anyone's interests but yours, and not really yours either.  You may of course say whatever you like, as you have said.  After all, anyone may turn this forum into a platform for exalting their ego if they care to.  However, it isn't particularly helpful to the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an implied "of things" in the sentence, so you are using it in the sense of the pronoun.  Look at these sentences, which should clarify the implied qualifiers:

> If you are looking for excitement, this job can give you plenty.
>   This job can give you plenty of excitement if you are looking for it.
>   You have given me plenty to think about.
>   You have given me plenty of things to think about.
>   I don't need more to eat, thank you; I have had plenty.
>   I have had plenty to eat, thank you.

The word in this context is synonymous with *a lot*.  *Plenty* in the noun sense is a bit different, because without any sort of qualifier expressed or implied it has the meaning you mention.

Answer (score 1):

This is what was meant. The word is used (in general usage) which may not always be consistent with what is listed in the dictionary. In the example sentence, it is used as a pronoun, but the following modifier/modifier phrase is left out in speech:

">**The psychological blow of his murder was "very demoralising for the opposition, as if they didn't already have plenty [of tragic events] to be demoralised about," said Gaddy.**

[image]